# Trying to use yui treeview inside of a cakephp view

Tags: php, cakephp, treeview, yui

I'd like to put a yui treeview inside of an add.ctp view in a cakephp application. I've got the treeview displaying fine but I'm trying to get a handle on how I can incorporate the treeview selected nodes with the post data that gets submitted by the cakephp view.

Comment: Well I think part of the solution involves setting the default and onsubmit arguments in $this->Form->create(). I believe I'm supposed to set 'default'=> false...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the same problem using JSON:

1. Create a JavaScript function that allow encoding of the YUI's selected nodes into a JSON string
2. Add the JSON string to a hidden field with the DOM properties

Answer (score 0):

Yes - I think that is essentially what I did. I added an onsubmit() function that would grab the values from the treeview using treeview.getNodesByProperty() and then would populate a hidden control in the form.